# Riddles involving Truth Tables

Tags: reference-request, logic, education

I'm looking for a simple riddle I can use to introduce the concept of a truth table.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are many of them in Smullyan, "What is the Name of This Book?" http://books.google.ca/books?id=MCqaYgEACAAJ